# Extract unicode characters within a certain range from a string

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I have a text file with a lot of junk characters.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shantanuo/marathi_spell_check/master/dicts/sample.txt

I need to keep only Devnagari characters. The expected clean output will look something like this...

```
भूमी
भूमी
भूमीला
भैय्यासाहेब
भैरवनाथ
भैरवी
भैरव
गावापासून
गा
```

As per this page, I need to extract all characters between unicode range of U+090 to U+097
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)

---

I tried this code, but it returns some foreign characters.

```
def remove_junk(word):
    mylist=list()
    for i in word:
        if b'9' in (i.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')):
            mylist.append(i)
    return (''.join(mylist))

with open('sample2a.txt', 'w') as nf:
    with open('sample.txt') as f:
        for i in f:
            nf.write(remove_junk(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: Your program will pick out code points with `9` anywhere in them, including the literal ASCII digit `9` itself as well as random code points like U+6789. It would vaguely work if you used `startswith()` instead of `in` (though you'd still need to exclude the literal digit `9`), but the regex answer is much better.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], which everyone can run to reproduce the issue? Chances are that the code for reading and writing files is not the problem, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all characters not within the unicode range U+0900-U+097F using regex.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'[^\u0900-\u097F\n]')   # preserve the trailing newline
with open('sample.txt') as f, open('sample2a.txt', 'w') as nf:
    for line in f:
        cleaned = p.sub('', line)
        if cleaned.strip():
            nf.write(cleaned)
```

---

**Minimal Code Sample**

```
import re

text = '''
‘भूमी
‘भूमी’
‘भूमी’ला
‘भैय्यासाहेब
‘भैरवनाथ
‘भैरवी
‘भैरव’
ﻇﻬﻴﺮ
（ページを閲覧しているビジターの使用言語）。
（缺少文字）
गावापासून
गा
'''

p = re.compile(r'[^\u0900-\u097F\n]')
for line in text.splitlines():
    cleaned = p.sub('', line)
    if cleaned.strip():
        print(cleaned)

# भूमी
# भूमी
# भूमीला
# भैय्यासाहेब
# भैरवनाथ
# भैरवी
# भैरव
# गावापासून 
# गा
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Python, but I guess it is possible to use Unicode properties in regular expressions just like in JavaScript, so it may possible to adapt the following script in some way, using the *Devanagari script* property:

```
var text =
`‘भूमी
‘भूमी’
‘भूमी’ला
‘भैय्यासाहेब
‘भैरवनाथ
‘भैरवी
‘भैरव’
ﻇﻬﻴﺮ
（ページを閲覧しているビジターの使用言語）。
（缺少文字）
﻿गावापासून
�गा`;
console.log (text.replace (/[^\r\n\p{Script=Devanagari}]/gu, ""));
```

which yields:

```
भूमी
भूमी
भूमीला
भैय्यासाहेब
भैरवनाथ
भैरवी
भैरव



गावापासून
गा
```